# IIS Rewrite for asp.net core,HTTP_METHOD unuse?

Tags: http, url, iis, http-put

My application( asp.net core 6) is deployed in a private cloud and works very well under IIS until now the cloud service has banned all PUT and DELETE requests. I have to convert them. I will convert PUT to POST on the client side and customize CUSTOM_METHOD:PUT so that it can pass through the cloud service gateway, I wanted to get to the server and use the IIS Rewrite to change HTTP_METHOD to PUT so I wouldn't have to change the code, but I found it didn't work very well. I log that IIS Rewrite has changed HTTP_METHOD to PUT, but my asp.net core 6 is still receiving POST, which my restful API can't handle.
[image]

Comment: _"the cloud service has banned all PUT and DELETE requests"_ - **que?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to change `HTTP_METHOD` (which you cannot unfortunately), you have to modify your code to use what Microsoft recommended, the header of `X-HTTP-Method-Override`.

It was initially documented in details in [ASP.NET 4.x](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers#example-x-http-method-override), and later echoed in [ASP.NET Core as a less documented middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: _"less documented"_ - pretty-much summarizes the state of .NET's documentation since .NET Core came out 

Comment: Thank you very much, I wanted to solve this problem in the outer layer (IIS) at first, when I tried many times (URLWRITE) failed, I checked the IIS log and found that the modification was successful, but at the program level it was still the original HttpMethod, until your answer I decided to give up. Using asp. Ent Core on Windows is always surprising.